# Why did the resistance's bullets become ineffective against Mech?

Tags: falling-skies

By the end of season 1, the resistance managed to build anti-mech ammo using salvaged Mech-metal.

But in season 2, their bullets barely scratched the Mechs and they had to resort to more powerful weapons to destroy them, like rockets, high caliber guns and explosives.

What happened? They doesn't appear to be any shortage of destroyed Mech bodies.  Did the aliens manage to adapt their shells against those bullets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When they left the school, they also lost the infrastructure needed to continue manufacturing the anti-mech bullets.  So at the start of season 2, which was 3 months later, they've long since run out of them.

This is explained in [a recent interview](http://io9.com/5918241/falling-skies-season-2-no-more-magic-bullets):

> In terms of the 'mech bullets,' because [the humans] are on the run, they're no longer based at the school, they no longer have the hardware or the ability to create these mech bullets.

Answer (score 5):

The official answer is they moved out of the school and lost the "infrastructure they needed to make more".

Logically this is rubbish as the first thing they would have moved would be the ability to make weapons that actually hurt the enemy.

I can't imagine the fighters of the second mass suggesting they leave behind the bullet molds and the shell casing, i.e. "we can't possibly carry the only thing that can save us from the aliens".

They've since been holed up in loads of places they could have easily made more.

Unofficially the real reason is that Cunningham didn't like the magic bullet idea so disposed of it. He wanted the humans to win by their ingenuity, not using a magic bullet.
I thought the mech metal bullets were pretty damn ingenious.

Comment: Lame. So now he's backpedaling on the writing because it's not dramatic enough?